# ctx.channel has type object "MISSING" with interactions module when trying to purge (Discord)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, discord-interactions

I tried making a command to purge messages with a slash command. However, I get a `AttributeError: type object 'MISSING' has no attribute 'purge'` error. Can anyone help me please?
Here's the code

```
# Les imports
import interactions
import os
import asyncio as a
from discord.ext import commands

# Le bot
slash = interactions.Client(token=token)

# Début du code
@slash.command(
    name="delete", 
    description="Supprime les X derniers messages",
    options = [
        interactions.Option(
            name="number_of_messages",
            description="Combien de messages à delete ?",
            type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
            required=True,
        ),
    ],
    )
async def delete(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, number_of_messages: str):
    await ctx.channel.purge(int(number_of_messages))

slash.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `discord-interaction` library anymore in `discord.py v2`. There already library to do it. So you can just using `discord.py`.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class your_class_name(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client:discord.Client):
        self.client = client

    @app_commands.command(name='purge', description="Delete a number of messages from a channel")
    @app_commands.checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def purge_message(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, number:int):
        //this way same as yours, but just using discord.py v2
        await interaction.channel.purge(limit=number)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{number} messages have been purged", ephemeral=True)
```

Make sure the one who want to use this purge command has `manage_messages` perms

Comment: Did this answer your question? If no, you should check discord.py documentation. There's a lot thing that you could see over there